# How to call a function in a View Model inside another View Model?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to separate my DevExtreme Scheduler in 2 view models. One is for the actual Scheduler and the other one is to show the Popup and handle the buttons. However i have everything but i cannot call the function inside the Popup view model.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var model = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("BookingScheduler"));

    var popup = new viewPopup();
    ko.applyBindings(popup, document.getElementById("BookingPopup"));

});
```

Inside my scheduler i have a click handler and inside it i want to call the `loadData` function which is in the popup view model.

```
function viewPopup() {
   function loadData(data) {
   }
}
```

This is how i tried to call it
`popup.loadData(data);` and `viewPopup().loadData(data);` and none of them work. I get **popup.loadData() is not a function**. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Why do you have 2 viewmodels for your page - if you just had 1 (perhaps with sub-view models) there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you create one main viewmodel and bind sub-viewmodels using the `with` binding:

```
var App = function() {
  this.scheduler = new viewModel();
  this.popup = new viewPopup();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  ko.applyBindings(new App());
});
```

With the HTML:

```
<body>
  <div data-bind="with: scheduler" id="BookingScheduler"></div>
  <div data-bind="with: popup" id="BookingPopup"></div>
</body>
```

Now, al though I'm not sure I'd recommend it, you can access the other vm using `$root.scheduler` from `popup`, and `$root.popup` from `scheduler`.

A better option could be to pass a reference to the `popup` viewmodel upon instantiation.

A third option is to use a "postbox" pattern ([like this plugin by R. Niemeyer](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox)).

Answer (score 0):

> Inside my scheduler i have a click handler and inside it i want to call the loadData function which is in the popup view model.

Then the scheduler viewmodel needs a reference to the popup view model. Swap round the order you declare them, and pass a reference in

```
var popup = new viewPopup();
ko.applyBindings(popup, document.getElementById("BookingPopup"));
var model = new viewModel(popup);
ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("BookingScheduler"));
```